# jwt token with encrypted private key and passphrase

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am tring to generate jwt token with below code

```
const { join } = require("path");
const { readFileSync } = require("fs");
const PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = join(__dirname, "./keys/private.pem");

const jws = require("jws");
const ALG = "PS256";

const privateKey = {
    key: readFileSync(PRIVATE_KEY_PATH, "utf8").toString(),
    passphrase: "Passphrasehere",
};
const payload = {
    foo: "bar",
};

const token = jws.sign({
    header: { alg: ALG },
    payload,
    privateKey,
});
```

But it showing error -

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: **The "key.key" property must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject. Received an instance of Object at prepareAsymmetricKey (internal/crypto/keys.js:288:13)**

Comment: Can you please add the issue or problem you are facing?

Comment: @SainPradeep I am facing this issue 

The "key.key" property must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject. Received an instance of Object

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/72415007/18954618

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem in your file reading.  Please check [Example](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs/) here

```
const fs = require('fs'); // missing in your code
// read file content in data
const data=fs.readFileSync(PRIVATE_KEY_PATH,{ encoding: 'utf8' });
  
const privateKey = {
        // pass data here
  key:data, 
  passphrase: 'Passphrasehere'
}
```

or try this

```
var cert = fs.readFileSync('PRIVATE_KEY_PATH'));
jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, { key: cert, passphrase: 'Passphrasehere' }, { algorithm: 'PS256'});
```

Comment: No i already use it there issue with "use private key with passphrase"

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try that.

Comment: issue is we can't pass object with private key in jwt.sign()

Comment: same error with packege (jsonwebtoken)
issue when we pass object 
jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, Object here  , { algorithm: 'PS256'});

Comment: can you please post the error message you receiving now?

Comment: same error showing

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key.key" property must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject. Received an instance of Object
    at prepareAsymmetricKey (internal/crypto/keys.js:288:13)

Comment: Please try assigning the private key file content to a variable and then pass into the sign method like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60553003/795683

Comment: but i need to pass passphrase with private key

when i not pass passphrase  then it showing error "passphrase is required with encrypted private key"

Comment: We only need to check when we pass hardcoded file content as a string in parameter code is working or not. Use current code same it is just hard code key values as shown in the example I posted above.

Comment: still same error with pass key with a variable